# zsh completion for media player

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In my `.zshrc`, I have `menu select` disabled globally, except for `mpv/mplayer`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=0
zstyle ':completion::complete:mpv:*' menu yes select
```

This works as expected, but I would like to modify the rule so that when menu is invoked, `mpv` only shows media files, ie 'mp3|mp4|mpg|avi|...'

I tried to change `*` to `*.mp3` to test it, but that does not work.

How do I have to modify my rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zstyle` completion settings affect how completions are displayed, and can tune how completions are generated, but does not determine the code to generate completions. That code is set with `compdef`, `compctl` or equivalent methods.

If you just want to specify media files as completions for `mpv`, call `compctl` in your `.zshrc`:

```
compctl -/ -g '*.(#i)(mp3|mp4|mpg|avi)' mpv
```

The `-/` option says to complete directories in addition to other completions (otherwise you wouldn't be able to reach files in subdirectories). The `-g` option specifies a glob pattern to select files for completion. `(#i)` causes a case-insensitive match.

For a more complex selection of completions, write a function (out of scope for this answer) and associate it with the command with `compdef` or through autoload magic. This function can query zstyle styles if it wants to tune how it generates completions.

Answer (score 0):

We could specify [`ignored-patterns`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignored_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style) with an extra `zstyle` line like this:

```
# append below line
zstyle ':completion::complete:mpv:*:*files' ignored-patterns '^*.(#i)(mp3|mp4|mpg|avi)'
```

PS: `^` is a "glob operator" such that `^x` matches anything except the pattern `x`, so above `zstyle` roughly means that please teach zsh to ignore non-media-ish files for `mpv` command.

> `ignored-patterns`
>
> A list of patterns; any trial completion matching one of the patterns will be excluded from consideration. The `_ignored` completer can appear in the list of completers to restore the ignored matches. This is a more configurable version of the shell parameter `$fignore`.
>
> Note that the [`EXTENDED_GLOB`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB) option is set during the execution of completion functions, so the characters ‘`#`’, ‘`~`’ and ‘`^`’ have special meanings in the patterns.
>
> --- [zshcompsys(1), zsh completion system, Standard styles](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignored_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things. (Note: This is not speculation. I’ve tested it and it works.)

First, you need define `file-patterns` for `mpv` in your `.zshrc`:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*:mpv:*' file-patterns \
        '%p.(mp3|mp4|mpg|avi)(#q^-/):globbed-files:"media file"' '*(-/):directories:directory' '*(#q^-/):all-files:file'
```

This tells Zsh's completion system that, on the first try, complete only files ending in the extensions specified (with the caption "media file", if you have `group-name` enabled). Only if that fails, will it offer directories. And only if that fails, too, offer any other kinds of files. (`(#q^-/)` matches only non-directories, whereas `(-/)` matches only directories.)

But that's not enough, because the completions supplied with `mpv` (and you did install those, right?), also try to offer URLs as completions. To avoid seeing those when there are media files available, add the following:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*:mpv:*' tag-order 'files'
```

This says that for the command `mpv`, it should first try to offer files (which includes everything under `file-patterns` above) and only when that fails, offer other things.